# How to animate React preloader disappearance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've faced a problem with removing preloader from the page smoothly.
At first I had a thought to change `content` variable and render it on the page but the preloader disappeared too fast.
I have created class `.closed` there is `opacity: 0;` but it doesn't work Thanks for help!

```
const App = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        }, 5000);
    });

    const content = loading ? <Preloader/> : <h1>Hello world!</h1>

    return (
        <div className='app'>
            {content}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Isn't the Preloader quickly disappearing a good thing? It's a sign your content has loaded quickly.

Comment: @Andy I'm actually just testing an artificial preloader before the client sees the main content. But I agree with your point of view.

Answer (score 0):

In this case try adding an empty dep array to your useEffect and cleaning it up after the your done with a return statement. Try something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(false)
  }, 5000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, []);
```

This way the the setTimeout is only called once on first render.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't solve my problem because preloader still disappears instantly. I want it to disappear smoothly using transition from `opacity: 1` to `opacity: 0`

Comment: Where is the Preloader component coming from? Does it take any props? When you say you created a closed class, did you add any keyframes to animate the opacity? Does the rendered component on the page actually have the class when you inspect? How Are you adding the class before you remove the component from the page? Note that even if you add the class but you remove the component immediately it won't show the opacity changing. You need to add a little more about what you are doing in order to help with a better answer.